# creating images from stream without header?

Tags: php, image, iostream

let's say I have the following:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
echo imagejpeg($image);
```

is it possible to display this as image without the need to display the headers (which will block other html rendering? or must I split it to several files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to just stick an image in a page is to encode it as base64, like this:

```
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode(imagejpeg($image, true)) . "\" />";
```

There are [serious limitations in doing it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images).  Instead, you should be referring to a separate script for your image:

```
<img src="yourimagescript.php" />
```